# What is the basis for number series vector space and number series with only finite nonzeros?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am confused about this when reading section 4.7 of 'Linear Algebra and Its Applications' 6th edition by David C.Lay

Consider 2 vector spaces:
$T_1$ = all number series, for example $(1,2,3,4,5,\ldots)$
$T_2$ = number series with only finite number of non-zeros, for example $(1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$

And consider a basis $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots\}$ for number series vector space, where
\begin{align*}
b_1 &= (1,0,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
b_2 &= (0,1,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
b_3 &= \ldots \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}

It seems that the 2 different vector spaces has the same basis. How is that possible? Where is the wrong of it?

Comment: elements of a vector space are *finite* linear combinations of basis vectors. for your first set of all sequences, the sequence of all 1's is not a finite linear combination of elements in your proposed basis.

Comment: A complete reference to the text in question would include, at the very least, the author(s).  There are probably several texts with that same title...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is given within the text itself. In the second-to-last paragraph of Section 4.7, on page 260, Lay writes:

> **The creative power of the shift LTI transformation falls short of being able to create a basis for $\mathbf S$ itself.** The definition of linear combination requires that only finitely many vectors and scalars are used in a sum. Consider the unit step signal, $v$, from Table 1. Although $v = \sum_{i=0}^\infty  S_i(\delta)$, this is an infinite sum of vectors and hence not technically considered a linear combination of the basis elements from $\mathcal B_f$.

[emphasis mine]

So this is the short answer: using the notions as defined in your text, your proposed basis is a basis for $T_2$, and is not a basis for $T_1$.

---

However, the relationship that you observe between the proposed basis and $T_1$ is not meaningless. But it is tricky enough to get correct that usually it is simply ignored in less advanced texts.

For instance, people do consider infinite sums, and you may be interested in the concept of a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis). However, the proposed basis is not a Schauder basis for $T_1$ in the usual sense because it does not play well with the notion of convergence.

This too can be overcome if one is willing to consider $T_1$ "in some other topology." What intuitively comes to mind when thinking about infinite sums in your basis like $\sum kb_k \to (1,2,3,\cdots)$ may be captured by the notion of [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series). Roughly, in that setting a sequence of sequences $(a_j)_i$ converges if for every sufficiently large $i$, their $j^\text{th}$ coordinates are all equal to each other. For instance, after the first two partial sums of $\sum kb_k$, the second coordinate is $2$ in all future partial sums.

(More powerful product topologies are also available, but for the sake of simplicity I'll leave it at that.)